# How can i find $Ω(f(n))$ and $O(f(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Given the following function,
$$f(n)=\prod_2^n \log i. $$ 
How can I find $f(n)=\Omega (?)$ and $f(n)=O(?)$ ?

I tried to do it, but I have no idea how to do it ..

Comment: You always have $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ and $f(n) = O(f(n))$.

Comment: Oh yes, this is the "trivial solution", the intention was for something different. Namely,  "?"= need to be "simple function" ... for example: $n$ , $nlog(n)$ , $n^2log(n)$ ...

Comment: 1. This looks like a pure math question to me.  Is there any reason why it is best answered by computer scientists, or needs a computer science perspective?  If so, please edit the question to clarify.  Otherwise, this might be better suited for [Math.SE].  2. You can convert a product to a sum by taking the log; and you can approximate a sum by taking the integral.  You might want to give that a try and see where it takes you.

Comment: [Our reference question may help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be easier to analyze $S(n) = \log f(n)$, which is given by the formula
$$ S(n) = \sum_{i=2}^n \log\log i. $$
According to the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula),
$$
S(n) = \int_2^n \log\log x \, dx + \frac{\log\log 2 + \log\log n}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^s \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} [(\log \log)^{(2k-1)}(n) - (\log\log)^{(2k-1)}(2)] + R,
$$
where the remainder satisfies
$$
|R| = O_s \left(\int_2^n (\log\log)^{(2s+1)}(x) \, dx\right).
$$
Here $(\log\log)^{(r)}$ is the $r$th derivative of $\log\log$ and $B_{2k}$ are Bernoulli numbers.

In order to get big O asymptotics, it suffices for the error to be of order 1. The first few derivatives of $\log\log x$ are
$$
\log \log x, \frac{1}{x\log x}, -\frac{\log x + 1}{x^2\log^2 x}, \frac{2\log^2 x + 3\log x + 2}{x^3\log^3 x}.
$$
The third derivative has constant sign (for $x$ larger than some constant), and so when $s=1$, the growth rate of the remainder term can be bounded by the second derivative evaluated at $n$, which is $o(1)$. So it suffices to choose $s=1$. We obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
S(n) &= \int_2^n \log\log x \, dx + \frac{\log\log 2 + \log\log n}{2} + \frac{\frac{1}{n\log n} - \frac{1}{2\log 2}}{12} + o(1) \\ &=
x\log\log x - Ei(\log x) \bigr|_2^n + \frac{\log \log n}{2} + O(1) \\ &=
n\log\log n - Ei(\log n) + \frac{\log \log n}{2} + O(1),
\end{align*}
$$
where $Ei(x)$ is [the exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). The exponential integral doesn't really reduce to any known function, but it is known that $E_i(x) = (e^x/x)(1 + O(1/x))$. Therefore
$$
S(n) = n\log\log n - \frac{n}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{n}{\log^2 n}\right).
$$
This gives the value of $f(n)$ up to a factor of $e^{O(n/\log^2 n)}$. In the same way, we can get an explicit expression with error $e^{O(n/\log^k n)}$ for any constant $k$, using the divergent series for $Ei(x)$. If we want an expression with $O(1)$ multiplicative error, then the best we can get is
$$
f(n) = \Theta(e^{n\log\log n - Ei(\log n)}\sqrt{\log n}).
$$
With a bit of effort we can also find the hidden constant.

Answer (score 4):

I won't even try to compete with Yuval's answer, but what are you going to do with a problem like this if you have no idea, and you are not a genius, and you want to get *some* result?

We can first observe that unlike other problems, in this case asking for $O (f (n))$ or $\Theta (f (n))$ means you need a very precise solution: The ratio between f (n) and f (n+1) is log (n+1) which goes towards infinity as n gets large. So if you manage to give an *exact* expression for f (n+1), then f (n+1) is *not* in $O (f (n))$!

Assuming that log(n) is the base 2 logarithm, log i ≥ 2 whenever i ≥ 4, which makes the product greater than $2^{n-3}$. log i ≥ 3 whenever i ≥ 8, so the product is greater than $3^{n-7}$ and so on. log i ≥ log n - 3 if i ≥ n / 8, so the product is also greater than $(\log n - 3)^{7n / 8}$, but less than $(\log n)^n$. So at least we can get a rough idea of how fast the product is growing, good enough to say that $\log f(n) = \Theta (n \log \log n)$, but nowhere near good enough for f (n) itself.